# Error when query Oracle: not a single-group group function

Tags: oracle, subquery, ora-00937

I have a query on **Oracle**:

```
SELECT count(*),SUM(price) as total_price,
  (SELECT count(*) as total_card_success FROM Card_trans WHERE status = 4)
FROM Card_trans;
```

When executing, it showed error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

How to solve this prob. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to count the number of rows where `status = 4`

```
SELECT count(*),
       SUM(price) as total_price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 4 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) some_alias
  FROM Card_trans;
```